# Idea for a project involving social media and ecommerce

Tags: facebook, neo4j, social-networking, atg, sap-commerce-cloud

I've been looking for an idea for a project incorporating social media functionalities into an eCommerce platform. I will be building my solution on top of the Hybris and ATG exemplary stores.

I'm looking to integrate Facebook and Google+, possibly also Twitter.

My current ideas, apart from the usual like, share, tweet, +1, involve:

- Facebook comments at the bottom of each product page
- Recommendations feed, which displays the most recommended content on the site
- Open Graph Tags - adding them to the < head > of the page will provide the crawler with structured info for the content

However, I feel that these are simple functionalities that can be implemented in a rather short period of time and don't require a lot of effort.

Therefore I am looking for something a bit more challenging. A friend of mine suggested I looked into [neo4j](http://neo4j.com/). It looks promising, however I haven't got a good idea of how I could use it in my project.

Have you got any interesting ideas for me? :)

Comment: Hybris is an really good choice to enhance with Neo4j, if you're in contact with the Hybris people ping them, they might be able to give you tips.

Comment: You should check out my series on Master Data Management in Neo4j for integrating different sites.  Part three will cover the actual integration stuff: http://blog.brian-underwood.codes/tag/master-data-management/

Comment: You can try [facebooksocialplugins](https://wiki.hybris.com/display/ylabs/facebooksocialplugins+AddOn+-+Technical+Guide)

Answer (score 0):

Recommendations are a clear addition to an e-commerce system.

Adding social, geo, look at the existing buying behavior. Find peer groups of the current user and see what they bought, also take other things into account, like items on sale, trending items, accessories to previous purchases, regular purchases.

Also price-management, fraud detection, catalogue management (esp. complex product catalogues), supplier relationships (order and contract mgmt.) etc.

Feel free to drop me an email michael at neo4j.org